# How is it possible to generate an OR like statement compile time? C++

Tags: c++, templates

I defined a function and a type enum like this:

```
enum ActionType : int {
    ACTION_FOO, ACTION_BAR, ACTION_BAZ
};

template<int T>
bool TestAction(std::string input, Result& result);
```

`TestAction` returns an indicator of success, and writes the output to the Result parameter. It is specialized for all `ActionType` values. I call it like this:

```
std::string input = "test";
Result res;
bool ok = TestAction<ACTION_FOO>(input, res) || TestAction<ACTION_BAR>(input, res) || TestAction<ACTION_BAZ>(input, res);
```

As soon as one call returns a true value, there is no need to call the other functions, so the `||` operator works well here.

The code works as intended, but I would like to avoid writing the `OR` statement by hand (or with macros), and instead generate a similar code compile time with templates. Is it possible somehow?

I can accept if I approach the problem from the wrong direction, but then please give me hints about how could I rework this code.

Comment: You can use a `tuple` of function pointers, but it doesn't seem worth it to me.

Comment: A tuple of function pointers is wholly and entirely unnecessary

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez I didn't think of taking advantage of the fact that it's always the same function template being called, so you can package template arguments instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T, T ...I, typename F>
bool static_any_of(F &&func, std::integer_sequence<T, I...>)
{
    return (func(std::integral_constant<T, I>{}) || ...);
}

template <auto N, typename F>
bool static_any_of_n(F &&func)
{
    return static_any_of(std::forward<F>(func), std::make_integer_sequence<decltype(N),N>{});
}

enum ActionType : int
{
    ACTION_FOO, ACTION_BAR, ACTION_BAZ,
    ActionType_Count,
};

int main()
{
    bool ok = static_any_of_n<+ActionType_Count>([](auto index)
    {
        return TestAction<ActionType(index.value)>(/*...*/);
    });

    std::cout << ok;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by writing a second version of TestAction that can accept multiple actions!

```
// This is our base case 
template<int T>
bool TestAction(std::string input, Result& result);

// This is the general case 
template<int T, int T2, int... Ts>
bool TestAction(std::string input, Result& result) {
    return TestAction<T>(input, result) || TestAction<T2, Ts...>(input, result); 
}
```

Then, to use it, we just provide the actions:

```
std::string input = "test";
Result res; 
bool ok = TestAction<ACTION_FOO, ACTION_BAR, ACTION_BAZ>(input, res);
```

**If you're using C++17,** we can also eliminate the recursion using a fold expression:

```
template<int... Ts>
bool TestActions(std::string input, Result& result) {
    return (TestAction<Ts>(input, result) || ...);
}
```

**Other recommendations:** If you're not modifying `input` anywhere in `TestAction`, you can eliminate copying by declaring `input` as a `const std::string&` so that it's passed by reference

Comment: This will copy `input` several times, not good. You can avoid recursion completely by using a fold expression instead: Remove `typename T` and do `return (TestAction<Ts>(input, result) || ...);`.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it by adding a second parameter to disambiguate the calls